# Which command will open the default browser on a system to a given web page (terminal)?

Tags: scripting, open-files, browser

Is there a way to open the default browser on a user's system to a specific page from within a Bash script, or other-language script?

Answer (score 3):

Best guess is [`xdg-open`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html) it should automatically fall-back to your Desktop environment to determine the browser.

Comment: Does this then allow the script to terminate, and still execute the command to open the default browser?

Comment: Did you mean "open the URL in background"? You can append `&` at the end of the command to tell it to execute in the background. For example `xdg-open http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44311 &`. In this case it's unnecessary because `xdg-open` opens the URL in the background by default.